# Null object reference even though i declared the checkbox

Tags: java, android

UPD: I'm sorry, apparently i added 2 id's to my checkbox cause i forgot to delete the default one

I am using a check box and I get this error when running apk:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

on the line I want to use checkbox.setOnClickListener

this is the code

```
final CheckBox settings_1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.settings_1);
settings_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( go_to_menu == 1)
            {
                settings_1.setChecked(false);
                go_to_menu = 0;
                SharedPreferences sharedpref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
                String key = getString(R.string.check1);
                editor.putInt(key, go_to_menu);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                settings_1.setChecked(true);
                go_to_menu = 1;
                SharedPreferences sharedpref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
                String key = getString(R.string.check1);
                editor.putInt(key, go_to_menu);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: so `settings_1` is not null? If it is, you should check `R.id.settings_1`

Comment: Please show your layout xml as well as the whole Activity class

Answer (score 1):

Probably this code is invoked before `setContentView()` or the layout of the activity not contain a view with id `settings_1`

Comment: i tought of that, and the code is invoked after setContentView() and there is a checkbox with the id settings_1 in the layout

Comment: Please, attach layout's xml-code